# Create ABAP DOC with Reference Link

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, abap

I am struggling to create a handsome ABAP Doc Documentation, and when I try to link the Docs to other Repository Objects (according to the syntax from [SAP Help Site](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-us/abendoccomment.htm)), this doesn't work:

```
    "! <h1>Method show</h1>
    "! Calls {@link cl_abap_browser.METH:show_html}
    "! @parameter html | 
   show,
```

I am getting the error message:

> *ABAP Doc Statement link is not valid at this Point*

Can somebody can help me with that?

Comment: The method `show` has no parameter `html`, therefore the syntax check will produce a warning.

Comment: Thats not the point unfortunately the statement above is also not accepted, but I will edit it here

Comment: Is your version >=7.52? I tried in my 7.50 and I got the same warning message but in the documentation for my version I can see that this is not yet supported: https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/index.htm The first one to have it seems to be 7.52

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature is only available from version 7.52 onwards, as documented in the specific release changes: https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abennews-752-abap_doc.htm